# source code of a transaction in ABAP-based systems?

Tags: abap

How can you look at the source code of a transaction in ABAP-based systems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can go to `System -> Status` and see the program name there.

After that you can go to Tcode `SE38` or `SE80` to view the coding.

Alternatively, you could key in /h to activate the debugging mode before you run the transaction.

Comment: How watch source code programm i know, i don't know how watch source code transaction.

Comment: the program name that you get with System->Status *is* the transaction.

Answer (score 3):

The exact answer to your question would be

```
?SYNTAX ERROR
```

A transaction does not have source code to look at. Take a look at various transactions using the transaction SE93. A transaction may name a program (report) to be executed - then you'll have to take a look at the source code of that program. A transaction may name a screen of a program, function pool or module pool to show - then you'll have to examine this screen and the subsequent ones. A transaction may simply delegate to another transaction using a variant, then you'll have to follow this link. [Read this](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw70/helpdata/en/43/2c43b427bf601fe10000000a422035/frameset.htm) for more info on the various types of transactions and what they are good for.

Answer (score 2):

Three options come to mind (I am sure there are many more):
1) In the transaction: menu System --> Status, the pop-up will show the program, double-click on it and it should take you there
2) Transaction SE93 is the transaction maintenance
3) Table TSTC keeps transaction codes and programs.

You can see the source code of a program in transaction SE80

Comment: These options no allow you to see the source code of the transaction, unfortunately ....