# Find a program by tcode

Tags: debugging, abap

I have a transaction code FTZZ and I can't find where to edit the code...I go to se38 it doesnt exits,go to se80 I try all of the above to edit or even find where the code was built I can't.

How can I find where this program was written and how can I edit it?

Comment: A transaction is a way of calling a program. Go to se93 and specify your tcode. You'll get the programs name which you can edit via se80 and se38.

Comment: @lausek that's right what about the function group?

Comment: Which function group do you mean?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [source code of a transaction in SAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972593/source-code-of-a-transaction-in-sap)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Three ways that I know

1. SE93 to display the TCode
2. Run the TCode, go to Menu: System->Status->SAP Data->Repository Data->Program
3. Run the TCode, click the arrow in the right-bottom corner of SAP GUI, then you will see a dropdown menu button, click it an you will see the full information like TCode, Program, System, Client, User, Response Time and so on.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Note that 2 and 3 might be misleading in some situations. For example if the original program `SUBMIT`'s to a different program or does a `CALL SCREEN` from inside a function module. I would generally recommend to use SE93 and then debug the program it references.