# How to find Function Group Name and Screen Number against T-Code or Programe Name in SAP?

Tags: abap, dynpro, function-module

I have requirement to fetch data base related information for extracting **function module group name and Screen Number for the corresponding T-Code** in SAP. Could You provide some idea for regarding this requirement.

Thanks for Advance...!

Comment: take a look at table TSTCP. Not sure how the parameters are stored in field PARAM, but they should be in there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [source code of a transaction in SAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972593/source-code-of-a-transaction-in-sap)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Gert.. Is there any possible way to find exact Screen Number against T-Code? I saw your answer but am started debugging it will execute more than 3000 lines of code. May I know how should I find efficient way to figure out this?

Comment: It's a bit hidden in all the answers, it's number 3 from HMa, the data you are looking for is in table TSTC.